# in my crystal report text object will get repeated every time for record

Tags: vb.net, vba, crystal-reports

Right Now i am just working with crystal report 10
I have a report which include many subreports 
In one of the many subreport i want to print like

```
< Detail Section >
    [Text Object :]   [Database Field]
                      [Database Field]
                      [Database Field]
                             .
                             .
</ Detail Section >
```

But It will Print Like

```
< Detail Section >
    [Text Object :]   [Database Field]
    [Text Object :]   [Database Field]
    [Text Object :]   [Database Field]
          .                   .
          .                   . 
</ Detail Section >
```

So kindly help me to get out of these problem
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Write Like Way:

< Detail Section >
    [Text Object :]   [Database Field]

```
                  [Database Field]

                  [Database Field]

      .                   .
      .                   .
```

or use top or bottom section for the one time data display

Comment: Thanks for reply .
but i just got the solution.
by right click on text object->format object and checked the option "Suppress if duplicate"